# Error in Stub creation from eBay Sandbox WSDL using Eclipse

Tags: java, wsdl, ebay-api, eclipse-wtp

I am using **Eclipse WTP plugin** to generate the stub from this WSDL: `https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi?wsdl`

But, when I do that, I get this error:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: WSDL2Java emitter timed out (this often means the WSDL at the specified URL is inaccessible)!
    java.io.IOException: WSDL2Java emitter timed out (this often means the WSDL at the specified URL is inaccessible)!
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.run(Parser.java:320)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.Emitter.run(Emitter.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.core.command.WSDL2JavaCommand.execute(WSDL2JavaCommand.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.ClientCodeGenOperation$ClientWSModifyOperation.execute(ClientCodeGenOperation.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.ClientCodeGenOperation.execute(ClientCodeGenOperation.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1318)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1289)
```

Any guesses why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, the WSDL is very big, so the sub creation timed out, here is the solution:

Disable the timeout in `Windows>Preferences>Web Services>Axis Emitter>Timeouts in Second = -1`

Answer (score 1):

While setting the timeout to `-1` (i.e. infinite or no timeout) would solve the timeout problem, it could pose a risk of having a hung eclipse workbench in a worst case scenario.  Setting it to a high enough value (e.g. `600`) should be a safer alternative.